# Is there someone who may explain can explain the behaviour of this javascript class?

Tags: javascript

```
class Group {
  constructor() {
    this.members = [];
  }

  add(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) {
      this.members.push(value);
    }
  }

  delete(value) {
    this.members = this.members.filter(v => v !== value);
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.members.includes(value);
  }

  static from(collection) {
    let group = new Group;
    for (let value of collection) {
      group.add(value);
    }
    return group;
  }
}

let group = Group.from([10, 20]);
console.log(group.has(10));
// → true
console.log(group.has(30));
// → false
group.add(10);
group.delete(10);
console.log(group.has(10));
```

First, I don't understand how this code with class create a new instance of the Group class without using the new operator
Second, I also have problem with the way the from method works

Comment: "*I don't understand how this code with class create a new instance of the Group class without using the new operator*" it calls `Group.from` which itself calls `let group = new Group;`

Answer (score 0):

This is almost identical to `Set` class, set is a list of non-duplicate values together.

> In mathematics, a set is a well-defined collection of distinct objects, considered as an object in its own right.

Just means that there may not be duplicate values*

```js
let set = new Set([1, 2, 3, 3])
// Set(3) {1, 2, 3}
set.add(3)
// Set(3) {1, 2, 3}
set.add(4)
// Set(4) {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

*however values that are accessed by reference (like arrays or objects) will cause duplicate values, because references are not compared by value, but by address in RAM

```js
let set = new Set([[1], [1]])
// Set(2) {[1], [1]}
```

Hence same references will be filtered out

```js
let ref = [1]
new Set(ref, ref)
// Set(1) {1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The static keyword defines a static method or property for a class. Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself. **Static methods are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects**, whereas static properties are useful for caches, fixed-configuration, or any other data you don't need to be replicated across instances.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Emphasis added by me.

There is no need to call the class constructor to be able to call a static method. The static method *from* does create a new instance via the new keyword (which in turn calls the constructor that initializes a new instance with a corresponding members property).